# VSTS Build defination fails at Get Sources step

Tags: build, azure-devops

VSTS Build definition fails at **Get Sources** step from TFS.

Below is the error:

> "error]Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessExitCodeException:
>   Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc get
>   /version:131 /recursive /overwrite D:\a\3\s /loginType:OAuth
>   /login:.,*** /noprompt'."

Please help.

Comment: Do you mean the Get sources step?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build directories? Tasks > Get sources > Clean: true, Clean options: All build directories. 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e792ef2e-1600-4127-a708-aab24329bfb9/exit-code-1-returned-from-process-file-name-tf-arguments?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: Can you share the screen shot for how the TFVC repo in Get sources step configured? And what's the agent did you use?

Comment: Yes, I meant Get Sources step. Sorry for the typo. I have selected the source TFVC and created a Map with server path. The "Local path under ($(build.sourcesDirectory)" is empty. If I put any local path there it does not save and gives this error "definition.Repository.Mappings.Mapping.LocalPath"

Comment: Agent used is "Hosted VS2017"

Comment: Do you still see this error? Can you share the detailed logs?

Answer (score 3):

You might see this error when the changes that you are trying to check in contain a file/folder to a location that is not mapped to list of sources with the build definition.

Error message is not beautiful enough but it is there to stop accidental check-ins.

Scan through your pending changes and see if there is any file that is from a folder that is not mapped as a source folder in build definition.

If there is one, either add that path to build definition folder list or move the files into a folder that is mapped as source folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close all projects.
   2 Connect to your repository.
2. In pending changes do not filter by any project, just see all files which is  it check-in.
3. Map and check-in files and folders.

Try to build again